# Cell array in first column, matrix in further columns in text file. How?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, text, matrix

```
A = {'Subject 1'; 'Subject 2'; 'Subject 3'; 'Subject 4'; 'Subject 5'}
```

With this I have their associated data:

```
ID = [1,2,3,4,5]

Score = [65, 90, 42, 53, 13]
```

I would like to output the data into the .txt file in this sort of format:

```
Screen Name       ID       Score
Subject 1          1          65
Subject 2          2          90
Subject 3          3          42
Subject 4          4          53
Subject 5          5          13
```

I know that I need to transpose the data first (thank you rayryeng)

```
ID = transpose(ID)
Score = transpose(Score)
```

So, **I updated the below code just now with the associated error:**

```
fileID = fopen('user_Database.txt', 'w');
fprintf(fileID,'%8s %16s %24s\n', 'Screen Name', 'ID', 'Score');
fprintf(fileID,'%8s %16.2f %24.2f\n', A{:}, ID, Score);
```

**Thank you Robert P.: it no longer crashes, HOWEVER it is not entering in the data for the second fprintf line. The first fprintf line is fine though...**

How would I have to write out the fprintf to incorporate the cell array in the first column, and the matrices in the subsequent columns?

Comment: It's no longer giving an error, but it's not printing out the data though. It's only printing out the first fprintf() line posted above.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you -

```
%// Inputs (slightly modified from original ones to show spacings are taken care of)
A = {'Subject 1'; 'Subject 2'; 'Subject 3'; 'Subject 4'; 'Subject 5'}
ID = [101,2,3,201,8]
Score = [165, 2090, 42, 53, 13]

%// Create cell array versions of ID and Score to account for proper
%// spacings between the prints of ID and Score
Score_cell = cellstr(num2str(Score.')); %//'
ID_cell = cellstr(num2str(ID.')); %//'

output_file = 'results.txt'; %//'# Edit if needed to be saved to a different path
fid = fopen(output_file, 'w+'); %// open file for writing

fprintf(fid, 'Screen Name\t  ID\tScore\n'); %// write the header line
for ii=1:numel(A)
    fprintf(fid, '%s\t %s\t %s\n',A{ii}, ID_cell{ii},Score_cell{ii}); %// write data
end
fclose(fid); %// close file as writing is done
```

Code run -

```
>> type results.txt

Screen Name   ID    Score
Subject 1    101      165
Subject 2      2     2090
Subject 3      3       42
Subject 4    201       53
Subject 5      8       13
```

Comment: Nevermind I can get back here if there is a problem. I am trying to test the code out with more columns. Thank you.